# Building a simple calculator in vba

Tags: vba

How can I make a label accepts multiple numbers from buttons, example if I hit a button that has "1" the label shows me 1, but if I hit another button like "2" the label replaces the 1 for the 2...it should show me "12" not replace the numbers...

this is my code for the label that will show the result as I press the buttons

```
Dim intNum1 As Integer
Dim intNum2 As Integer
Dim intNum3 As Integer
Dim intNum4 As Integer
Dim intNum5 As Integer
Dim IntNum6 As Integer
Dim IntNum7 As Integer
Dim IntNum8 As Integer
Dim IntNum9 As Integer





Me.txtEntry_Result.Text = intNum1 & intNum2
```

Comment: What do you need all those integers for? You can directly update the caption of a label when you click a button.

Comment: I was trying a method each integer correspond to a space in the label

Answer (score 0):

if  `txtEntry_Result` is the label

then you should use the `.Caption` Property of that object.

like this `Me.txtEntry_Result.Caption = intNum1 & Me.txtEntry_Result.Caption` it will concatenate `Me.txtEntry_Result.Caption` with new number and assign it back to it.

> How can I make a label accepts multiple numbers from buttons, example if I hit a button that has "1" the label shows me 1, but if I hit another button like "2" the label replaces the 1 for the 2...it should show me "12" not replace the numbers..

You can do it like this for example for Button1

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Me.txtEntry_Result.Caption = Me.txtEntry_Result.Caption & Me.CommandButton1.Caption 
End Sub
```

Similarly for every other button you can do it like that.

Comment: Im programming in vba in access 2013 that shouldnt be a problem...but..it returns me Compilation error: method or data member not found :/ in the buttons_Click

Comment: Ohh Sorry I didn't know this was for access you should've added the `access` tag. Anyway that error means the Button name is wrong so change the code according but the logic is right.

Comment: Yes!, it worked! but instead the txtEntry_Result.Caption I used txtEntry_Result.DefaultValue